# Where to store payment gateway secret key when using python Django with apache server hosted on aws ec2 Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

Where to store payment gateway secret key when using python Django with apache server?

I don't what to store in settings.py as i will checking this file in my git.

Can i do it the same way amazon store AWS ec2 keys. If possible how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set secrets in environment variables and get them in python code as `password = os.getenv('ENVNAME')`.